# My object is disappearing when i go in to object mode

Tags: modeling, mesh, interface

For some reason when i go in to object mode my object disappearing.

[image]

I don't want to do my model again please help me.

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. You mean if you `tab` into *Edit Mode* it disappears? Just press `Alt+H` to make it show up

Comment: What modifiers have you used? Any of them might have been bugged? I had similar problem previously. Subdivision modifer was dysfunctional, causing 3D model to disappear in the Object Mode. I had previously asked question in hub. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/308226/why-is-the-modifier-subdivision-not-working

Comment: Go to your User Preference and check settings inside the Viewpoint. Go to Subdivision and check if GRU subdivision is ticked on. That brings back object's visibility in the Object Mode. I hope that fixes your problem. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_LmyfQNB-pY&t=11s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your screenshots show it's disappearing in *Edit Mode*, not in *Object Mode*. So most probable you have selected everything in *Edit Mode* and pressed <kbd>H</kbd> to hide it. To make it visible again you have to be in *Edit Mode* and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to *Unhide Everything*.