# Why is the modifier subdivision not working?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I enclose a video. Below, I test settings in the Subsidivion modifier and nothing seems to be working. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: The [modifier is currently disabled in Edit Mode](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/introduction.html#interface) and the video shows that Blender is in Edit Mode.

Comment: Agreed. Click the hollow box icon with the dot in one corner on the modifier panel to enable it in Edit mode.

Comment: I have already tried clicking the dot in Edit Mode, but the modifier is still dysfunctional. This has never happened to me before.

Comment: I got the problem solved. I first watched a tutoral "Blender 3.1 | Subdivision Surface isn't working" as in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_LmyfQNB-pY&t=11s. I followed instructions. I went to Preferences > Viewport and changed settings therein. All is ok. Thanks everybodyl